# Can I post a challenge that is the same as an existing challenge but with different criteria?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Let's say I find an awesome challenge here, but I can make a different challenge out of it by changing the criteria significantly. Is it poor form to post a new challenge with a completely different set of criteria?

If there is no general answer to this I can describe the specific example I'm thinking of and what I intend to post.